# How to add jQuery fadeIn on scroll to Angular application

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Let me preface this by saying that I realize this is terrible practice. However, **is it possible to use jQuery to fade in images on scroll in an AngularJS project?**

I've got a tight deadline at work, and need to make this Angular project look better. I don't have the time to wrap my head around the Angular way of doing this at the moment, so the quick and dirty will have to suffice.

Here's where I'm at:

I have a controller, LandingCtrl

```
angular.module('appName.controllers', [])
       .controller('LandingCtrl',  ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);
```

And I have a view with a bunch of divs in it that I want to fade in as the user reaches them.

Using jQuery alone, it would be pretty straight forward, something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/tcloninger/e5qaD/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll( function(){

        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.hideme').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

            }

        }); 

    });

});
```

However, when I try to use that jQuery function in my controller that is scoped to the view in question, I get all kinds of problems.

Is there any way to do this properly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use jquery, you can just stick (pretty much) what you have in a directive:

```
angular
    .module('app', [])
    .directive('scrollContainer', scrollContainer)



function scrollContainer($window) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {

                $('.hideme').each( function(i){

                    var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
                    var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

                    /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
                    if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

                        $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

                    }
               });
           });
        }
    }
}
```

```
<body ng-app="app">

    <div id='container' scroll-container>

        <div>Hello</div>
        <div>Hello</div>
        <div>Hello</div>
        <div>Hello</div>
        <div>Hello</div>
        <div>Hello</div>
        <div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
        <div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
        <div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
        <div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
        <div class="hideme">Fade In</div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Plunker appears to be down, so i've stuck a working example on codepen

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgBzPg